# Error in converting datetime from string to datetime object in python

Tags: python, datetime

I am converting a date in the string to datetime object like this

```
datetime_object = datetime.strptime('2019-07-01T07:52:48.337-0700', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f-%Z')
```

Here I'm not understanding what the `0700` is?
Is it timezone? Isn't `%Z` or `%z` the right directive for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-` is part of the timezone offset `-0700` (the `%z` directive, lowercase z), you should not have it in the format string:

```
datetime_object = datetime.strptime('2019-07-01T07:52:48.337-0700',
                                    '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z') # no - between %f and %z
```

`%Z` (uppercase Z) is for timezone **name** (UTC, EST, etc..)

Comment: It says ValueError: 'z' is a bad directive in format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z'

Comment: Oh just got to know that Python 2 does't support offsets. Thanks.

Comment: @AdityaJha Then consider upgrading to Python 3